# How to pipe output of 'say' to another command

Tags: audio, command-line

'say' has both -o and -n arguments for various ways to direct the output, but I don't see any way to simply pipe the output to another command (say, sox).  Is this a limitation of say, or is there a basic Unix shell feature that will do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems impossible. It *should* have been possible to use `-o /dev/stdout` for this, but `say` insists on adding a file suffix, which rather ruins that option. I tried getting around that by creating a symlink to `/dev/stdout`, but it gives a permission error. (Perhaps this comes from `say` opening the output file for both reading and writing (option `O_RDWR`) instead of just writing.)

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know about /dev/stdout.  While not a solution here, it's good to know about for the future.

Comment: I also was interested in piping "say" (well, using its output in a Python program without first saving to a file). I believe Harald is correct as I came to the same conclusion when I checked. I ended up using "espeak" instead, which does allows you to pipe raw wav data. Of course, it's one more thing to install, but it does the job.